# chess.js: Move validation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a chess game in react.js using the libraries [chess.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chess.js) and [chessboard.jsx](https://chessboardjsx.com/)

Currently i am trying to implement move validation with the following code :-

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Chessboard from "chessboardjsx";
import * as ChessJS from "chess.js"; // import { Chess } from 'chess.js' gives an error

function App() {
  const Chess = typeof ChessJS === "function" ? ChessJS : ChessJS.Chess; // For VS code intellisence to work
  const game = new Chess();

  const [position, setPosition] = useState("start");

  const onDropMove = ({ sourceSquare, targetSquare }) => {
    const move = game.move({
      from: sourceSquare,
      to: targetSquare,
      promotion: "q",
    });

    if (move === null) return;

    setPosition(game.fen());
  };

  return <Chessboard position={position} onDrop={onDropMove} />;
}

export default App;
```

But the problem coming is:-
For example: -  When i move white pawn from g2 to g3 it works but then if i try to move the black pawn from g7 to g6, it counts it as an illegal move(i checked by console.log(move)) although it is legal.

I don't have any idea why this is occurring. Also, I did not find any answers online regarding this issue

Comment: Do you have to explicitly change the turn from white to black after the first move? That second move would be invalid if it were still evaluating as a white move.

Comment: No, i checked the turn was of black by console.log(game.turn());

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but here's a solution.

Basically, just define the chess.js API as follows:

```
const [game, setGame] = useState();

useEffect(()=>{
    setGame(new Chess())
  }, [])
```

Hope this helps!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this when you are defining the state give the game state as new Chess() see code below.

```
  const [game, setGame] = useState(new Chess());
```